# SQL: how to copy value of meta_key inside array in another meta_key?

Tags: sql, wordpress

*I'm asking here since seems more like a SQL question than WordPress.*

I have a WordPress installation using custom fields from a template and custom fields from a plugin (ACF). There are thousands of posts using the custom field from ACF, "subtitle".

Now I need to move all "subtitle" values to the other custom field, "td_subtitle". I found [a simple answer in SQL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232618/move-value-of-one-custom-field-to-another#_=_) being:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'subtitle' where meta_key = 'td_subtitle';
```

But checking my database, the value of "td_subtitle" is inside an array, like this:

```
a:1:{s:11:"td_subtitle";s:24:"This is a post subtitle blablabla";}
```

"td_subtitle" is inside "td_post_theme_settings" meta_key.

[image]

**Question**: how to move all values from "meta_key > subtitle" to "meta_key > td_post_theme_settings > td_subtitle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WP `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`. check the below code.

```
$td_post_theme_settings = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'td_post_theme_settings', true );

$td_post_theme_settings['td_subtitle'] = 'subtitle';

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'td_post_theme_settings', $td_post_theme_settings );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)
- [update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I made it using update_post_meta. According to another topic, it's impossible to SQL do deal with arrays inside meta_keys, so I would never do the way I was trying.